# Chat system in Zend Framework website

Tags: php, zend-framework, networking, chat

In my website, I have to make a chat system similar to Gmail so registered users can chat with their group. I have no idea about how I will do this. Can anyone provide me with an idea of how to implement this or any useful links? I have to do it using Zend Framework.

Comment: Well, you will need to learn AJAX. You should probably use some framework like jQuery.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking to work this out using Zend framework, have a look at [Jaxl library](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL) (Jabber XMPP Client/Component Library). The library can be integrated with any existing website/framework and also contains several examples for browser based chat applications.

Comment: Jabber XMPP is best available , i like it :)

Comment: absolutely... XMPP is best suited for the kind of application you are trying to build... Do let me know if Jaxl library helped u out in your app...

Comment: If you run a XMPP server, then look into BOSH as well. BOSH is essentially a Comet / Reverse-Ajax implementation that has been standardized for XMPP. With Strophie (Javascript XMPP client), you can have live chats on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are two parts for chatting:

- A long running request that streams massges from the server to the client
- Ajax messages from the client to the server that sends one message to the server

For the second, any ajax framework will do it. For the first you might have a look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to get the idea for this. But you should be aware that html isn't ment to be a chatting protocol. If you don't pay attention such stuff can easily kill your server.